# Warning regarding minitest/unit when used with ActiveSupport-4.1.1.gem? How to resolve this?

Tags: ruby, rspec, minitest, activesupport

I've searched google and github about the following warning (see more detail below) that I am receiving when I run my tests on my gem, which, all pass:

```
Warning: you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead.
Warning: or add 'gem "minitest"' before 'require "minitest/autorun"'
```

I've not encountered any real solution to the issue, and the warning is not clear on where to require 'minitest/autorun' or why I would need to add 'gen "minitest'" since it appears that activesupport-4.1.1.gem pulls it in (it is in my vendors\gems folder). Is there a way to remedy this just when running my tests, because it is only a warning when I run tests :S

**My .gemspec file...**

```
 # LittleWeasel pulls in activesupport-4.1.1...
 spec.add_runtime_dependency 'LittleWeasel', '~> 2.1.2'
 spec.add_runtime_dependency 'ProtectedConstructor', '~> 1.0.5'
 spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.3"
 spec.add_development_dependency "rake"
 spec.add_development_dependency "rspec", "~> 2.13.0"
 spec.add_development_dependency "yard", "0.8.6.2"
 spec.add_development_dependency "redcarpet", "~> 2.3.0"
```

**Warning Received...**

```
/Users/userabc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/vendor/bundle/bin/rspec /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/test --require teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter --format Spec::Runner::Formatter::TeamcityFormatter --pattern **/*_spec.rb
Testing started at 10:38 AM ...
Warning: you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead.
Warning: or add 'gem "minitest"' before 'require "minitest/autorun"'
From:
  **/Users/userabc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/assertions.rb:1:in `require'
  /Users/userabc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/assertions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'**
  /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/lib/MonkeyEngine/exceptions.rb:1:in `require'
  /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/lib/MonkeyEngine/exceptions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/lib/MonkeyAction/monkey_action_dead.rb:2:in `require'
  /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/lib/MonkeyAction/monkey_action_dead.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/lib/MonkeyActions.rb:1:in `require_relative'
  /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/lib/MonkeyActions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/lib/Monkey/monkey.rb:3:in `require'
  /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/lib/Monkey/monkey.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/lib/Monkey.rb:1:in `require_relative'
  /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/lib/Monkey.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/test/rspec/action_rules_spec.rb:3:in `require'
  /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/test/rspec/action_rules_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
  /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
  /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
  /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
  /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
  /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
  /Users/userabc/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

**EDIT**

**Top of action_rules_spec.rb file:**

```
require_relative 'spec_helpers'

require 'Monkey'
require 'MonkeyFactory'
require 'MonkeyEngine'
require 'MonkeyManager'
require 'MonkeyActions'
require_relative '../../lib/MonkeyKeyboard/keyboard_input'

describe 'ActionRules' do
...
```

**spec_helpers.rb:**

```
module SpecHelpers

  module SetMonkeyAction
    def set_action(action)
      @action = action
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you show us what's in `action_rules_spec`? especially the first few lines?

Comment: It's important to show a reduced version of your code that demonstrates the problem. From your example we can't tell what you're doing in your test where you should be subclassing MiniTest. Your Ruby is very out of date, which could be contributing to the problem. Ruby is past 2.1 now.

Comment: @UriAgassi added a few lines from action_rules_spec.rb and spec_helpers.rb.  I'm not using minitest, I'm using rspec; minitest.gem is only there because of the ActiveSupport-4.1.1.gem :S

Answer (score 2):

Minitest 5 has changed the base test class API to `Minitest::Test` from `MiniTest::Unit::TestCase` in MiniTest 4. It also changed the require to `minitest/test` from `minitest/unit`, although using `minitest/autorun` will do the right thing.

ActiveSuport 4.0 used to depend on MiniTest 4, but ActiveSuport 4.1 depends on Minitest 5.

You have something in your app that is requiring `minitest/unit`. This looks to be RSpec version 2.13.1, which is more than a year old. Try upgrading RSpec to a more recent version.

Comment: ty. I updated rspec to 3.0.0, and now getting this exception:

/Users/gangelo/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1018:in `require': cannot load such file -- teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter (LoadError)
 from /Users/gangelo/RubymineProjects/monkeyengine/vendor/bundle/gems/rspec-core-3.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1018:in `block in blah blah bla